# Filtering Multiple items with ES6 array functions

Tags: javascript, arrays

This code only excludes **John** whats the best way of filtering out **John**, **Brian** and **James**?

```js
const names = ["John", "Mary", "Max", "Brian", "James"]
const filterdNames = names.filter((value) => {
  return value !== 'John' && 'Brian' && 'James';
});
console.log(filterdNames)
```

Comment: Almost all programming languages I know (including javascript) will interpret that as `(value !== 'John') && ('Brian') && ('James')`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
const names = ["John", "Mary", "Max", "Brian", "James"]
const filterdNames = names.filter((value) => {
  return ["John", "Brian", "James"].includes(value) === false;
});
```

You can use [Array.includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)

Answer (score 2):

Create an array of the names you want to filter out beforehand, and then you can just test for the negation of an `includes` on it:

```js
const names = ["John", "Mary", "Max", "Brian", "James"];
const filterOut = ['John', 'Brian', 'James'];
const filterdNames = names.filter(value => !filterOut.includes(value));
console.log(filterdNames)
```

Answer (score 2):

You are close, but your code is slightly wrong. You need to add `value !==` for each condition.

```js
const names = ["John", "Mary", "Max", "Brian", "James"]
const filterdNames = names.filter((value) => {
  return value !== 'John' && value !==  'Brian' && value !==  'James';
});
console.log(filterdNames)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const names = ["John", "Mary", "Max", "Brian", "James"]
const filterdNames = names.filter((value) => {
  return value != "John" && value != 'Brian' && value != 'James';
});
console.log(filterdNames)
```

Answer (score 0):

A string which is greater than or equal to one character long, will evaluate to true when coerced into a boolean. `&&` is the logical AND operator. So in your filter you are stipulating that the name is not equal to John AND true AND true. You want to say, if the name is NOT John AND the name is NOT Brian AND the name is NOT James. It should look like this.

```js
const names = ["John", "Mary", "Max", "Brian", "James"]
const filterdNames = names.filter((value) => {
  return value !== 'John' && value !== "Brian" && value !== "James"
});
console.log(filterdNames)
```

Comment: Makes sense. fundamentals